# How to import my current wallet in Mist?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, wallets, import

I generated my wallet with geth command line "geth new account", with password, and got my key.

Following a guide, I just downloaded Claymore's Dual Miner, setup the start.bat pasting my key and started mining on Nanopool. 
Now I'm about to get my first payment reaching the minimum payout so... what should I do? I found the Mist Wallet to keep track of my wallet, is this the correct way? should I import my key in some way in it? 
Please help, because I think I miss something very basilar..

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can check your public address here to see your balance: https://etherscan.io/

You can use myetherwallet to send or interact with ethereum network: https://www.myetherwallet.com/

Be careful!  make sure you are on the secure https sites for the above and avoid phishing sites.

There are other ways, but these are the ones I use.

Comment: so, if I got it right.. I should send my ETH from myetherwallet to some account like Kraken , then sell and buy there?

Comment: Yes that would work. Keep your keys very safe and secure and keep multiple copies.

Answer (score 0):

Mist by default accesses the keystore folder in `.ethereum` directory for accounts. 
If you are on linux, there will be a `.ethereum` folder in your home directory (`/home/your_user`). Just paste you account file in that folder, Mist will automaticlly detect it.

Keep in mind, you balance may not be updated if your blockhain is not synced.

The default location of `.ethereum` folder is:

- **Windows:** ~/AppData/Roaming/Ethereum
- **OS X:** ~/Library/Ethereum
- **Linux:** ~/.ethereum

Comment: I am under windows, cannot find the .ethereum folder, in C:\Geth I only have the uninstaller and the .exe

Comment: Edited the answer.